# Why is this react component not displaying content loaded?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I'm working on this project and I want to display the content I got from the backend routes via axios to Showcase component. But the code doesn't give the output as expected the updated state console.log(cont) is working and no issue but it doesn't rendering contents.The app.js state is received by the component. I want to display the names. The child functional component as follows.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    Table,
    Button
} from 'reactstrap';

function Showcase(props) {
    const title = props.title;
    const contents = props.contents;
    let items_body = [];

    items_body = contents.map(cont => {    
        console.log(cont)
        if(cont.category === 'Men') {
            return (
                <div className="item_card" key={cont._id}>
                    <div className="itemC_right">
                        <div className="itemCR_topA">
                            <div className="itemCR_topA_title">{cont.name}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
        }
        else if(cont.category === 'Women') {
            return (
                <div className="lead content d-flex d-flex justify-content-center mb-3" key={cont.id}>
                    <div>Name : {cont.name}</div>
                </div>
            )
        }
        else if(cont.category === 'Kids') {
            return (
                <div className="lead content d-flex d-flex justify-content-center mb-3" key={cont.id}>
                    <div>Name : {cont.name}</div>
                </div>
            )
        }
        else 
            return (
                null
            )
    })

    return (
        <div id="showcase">
            <div id="showcase_card">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-sm-6 d-flex flex-row mt-1">
                        <h1 className="display-3 txt_secondary text-left" id="showcase_title">{title}</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-sm-6 d-flex flex-row-reverse mt-4">
                        <small className="txt_secondary text-right">Oreo is a online shopping store made just for you.</small>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div>
                    {items_body}
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    )

}

export default Showcase;
```

The App.js class component

```
class App extends React.Component {      
  state = {
    title: 'Oreo',
    contents: []
  }

  changeState = (category,data) => {
    this.setState({
      title: category,
      contents: data
    })
  }

  handleNavigation = (e) => {
    const option = e.target.innerHTML;
    switch(option) {
      case "Men":
          axios.get('/api/items/men/2')
            .then(res => {
              this.changeState('Men',res.data);
              // console.log(res.data)
            })
        break;
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <NavigationBar handleNavigation={this.handleNavigation} />
        <Showcase title={this.state.title} contents={this.state.contents} />
        <ItemWindow />
        <BottomBar />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

In NavigationComponent.js when clicked on Men I'm sending it to App.js then it handles the click event. Why doesn't Showcase.js cannot show/render results? Help.

Comment: `items_body` is an array, right. it's an array of different divs which you want to display. so, inside the render function instead of `{items_body}` you should `{items_body.map((item) => {
  return <div>{item}</div>
} )}` or something similar. in short, you should manually display all divs from your array.

Comment: another thing to consider is the Axios call is async so I guess the handleNav function should be async and you should await for the response.

Comment: handleNavigation = async (e) // await axios.get('/api/items/men/2') } I changed it like this but it still not working

Comment: I am glad you got some results. Keep in mind I didn't actually run the code provided. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

So I got rid of the if statements under the Showcase.js and could get my results. It seems that I was checking the category twice(in handleNavigation and here). I also added async and await as tonkalata's way.